# jQuery & Django: how can I use jquery properly in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I'm having hard time with `js` and `jquery` executing events, I guess there is something I'm missing in my understanding of jquery.
Because I'm really new to this language, I'm confused and need some orientation if you can help me please.

**what I need:**
I have a form as a row, and a button that adds a new form everytime I click on it. also the new generated forms have different Ids and names.
Now every form contains two `selects` and need a `change` function to be excuted on it. 
Where should I write this `change` function, so that every row have his own `change` function without getting confused with other rows.

**EDIT :**

```
<div id="myDIV1" style="display: inline">
    <form action="/banque"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="personForm" data-tiers-url="{% url 'ajax_load_tiers' %}" >{% csrf_token %}{{ form.non_field_errors }}  

<table style ="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 15px;" id="id_forms_table">

            <tr><td width="5%">N P</td><td width="8%">Date d'operation</td><td width="25%">Désignation</td><td width="10%">Type tiers</td><td width="10%">Tiers</td><td width="10%">Référence de Facture</td><td width="10%">Montant debit </td><td  width="10%">Montant crédit</td></tr>
            {% for form in formset %}
         <tr style="border:1px solid black;" id="{{ form.prefix }}-row" class="dynamic-form" >

            <td{% if forloop.first %} class="" {% endif %}><div class="col-xs-1"><b><p name="np1">1</p></b></div></td>
            <td>
                {% render_field form.dateOperation class="form-control"  %}{{form.dateOperation1.errors}}

            </td>
            <td>{% render_field form.designation  class="form-control"  %}{{form..errors}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% render_field form.typeTiers class="form-control" %}{{form.typeTiers.errors}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% render_field form.tiers class="form-control" %}{{form.tiers.errors}}
            </td>
            <td>{% render_field form.numfacture class="form-control"   %}{{form.numfacture.errors}}
            </td>
            <td>{% render_field form.montantdeb class="form-control"  %}{{form.montantdeb.errors}}</td>
            <td>{% render_field form.montantcred class="form-control"  %}</td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>

            </tr>
</table>
{{ formset.management_form }}
<tr>
    <!-- BUTTONS <td colspan="4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-row">add property</a></td> -->
    <td width="16%"><input type="submit" name="annuler" value="Annuler" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:right ;margin: 5px; margin-right: 35px"></td>
    <td width="16%"><button value="" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;margin: 5px;" onclick="verifier()">enregistrer</button></td>    

</form>

<td><input type="submit" name="ajoutligne" value="Ajouter une ligne" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-row" style="background-color: #8C1944; border-color: #8C1944; float:right;margin: 5px;" onclick="test()"></td></tr>

</div>
```

On change of each added row by the button `Ajouter une ligne` , I need to execute the following change function:

```
$("#id_form-"+0+"-typeTiers").change(function () {
        alert($('#id_form-'+0+'-typeTiers').attr('name'));
        var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-tiers-url"); 
        var typeID = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({         
        url: url,
        data: {
          'tiers': typeID,
        },
        success: function(data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
           alert(data);
           var i=1;
           var listeClt = $(data).clone(true).find('option[id=facvente],option[id=fadepenses],option[id=frs]').remove().end().html();
           var listefactVentes= $(data).clone(true).find('option[id=clt],option[id=fadepenses],option[id=frs]').remove().end().html();
           var listefrs = $(data).clone(true).find('option[id=facvente],option[id=fadepenses],option[id=clt],option[id=cnss]').remove().end().html();
           var listefactDep= $(data).clone(true).find('option[id=clt],option[id=facvente],option[id=frs]').remove().end().html();
          // var cnss= $(data).clone(true).find('select').remove().end().html();
          if(listeClt!=0){
           $("#id_form-"+0+"-tiers").html(listeClt);
           $("#id_form-"+0+"-numfacture").html(listefactVentes);
}
else if(listefrs!=0){

           $("#id_form-"+0+"-tiers").html(listefrs);
           $("#id_form-"+0+"-numfacture").html(listefactDep);
}
else {

           $("#id_form-"+0+"-tiers").html(data);
}


       }
    });
        });
```

`"#id_form-"+0+"-typeTiers"`  is the id of the first row `select` , `"#id_form-"+0+"-tiers"` is the Id of the select that will get populated after changing `"#id_form-"+0+"-typeTiers"` of the same row.
this jquery changes the first row correctly, but what about rows tha will be add after ? their fields will have as Ids `1 , 2 ..`  etc instead of `0` .
Any help would be great. Thank You in advance

Comment: Show your code, so we can understand more. there are question came up my mind, 1) Is it Admin form? 2) Is it normal html? 3) Is it CreateView, UpdateView? where is the issue?

Comment: It's not an admin form, and it's not normal html, i'm working with django formsets. I will add my code

Comment: @AnupYadav I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please look on this some samples. it may helps you

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Insert-Remove-Delete-Table-Rows-dynamically-using-jQuery.aspx

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-append-and-remove-table-row-dynamically